# how to control test cases to run on different browsers in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

[test problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdbu9.jpg)

as seen in test problem pic, there are two browsers that run different test cases. i want to run spec 7 on both running browsers( browser1 and browser2) with interaction like chat application. after running specs 1 to 6 on both browser, spec 7 should run on both browser with specified tests. for example:

### spec7.js file:

- user1 sends hello msg from browser1 to user2 in browser2.
- user2 recieve hello msg in browser2 and send msg hi from browser2 to 
  user1 in browser1.

These both actions should be done in same spec7.js file and this file should be run in both browser that are running already for other specs file.
i am seeking a help.

Comment: Why do you don't want to use two separate files to test the interactions?

Comment: if i user two separate files, then how to do following thing: browser1 sends msg to browser2, browser2 waits for browser1 msg and after getting msg from browser1, browser2 sends reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two file to solve your issues.

I try to explain it with a sample chat application

**spec7_browser1.js:**

```
...
//Sends own message
element(by.id('messageInput')).sendKeys('hello'); // Enters hello into the message input field

element(by.id('submitMessage')).click(); // Clicks on the submit button to send the message

expect(element(by.id('chat')).getText()).toContain('hello');

// Waits for the message of browser 2
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.id('chat')), 'hi'), 60000); // Waits until the given text is displayed in the element and fails if the text is not displayed in 60 seconds 

expect(element(by.id('chat')).getText()).toContain('hi');
...
```

**spec7_browser2.js:**

```
...
// Waits for the message of browser 1
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.id('chat')), 'hello'), 60000); // Waits until the given text is displayed in the element and fails if the text is not displayed in 60 seconds 

expect(element(by.id('chat')).getText()).toContain('hello');

// Sends own message
element(by.id('messageInput')).sendKeys('hi'); // Enters hello into the message input field

element(by.id('submitMessage')).click();

expect(element(by.id('chat')).getText()).toContain('hi');
...
```

And so on...

Maybe you need to increase the default timeout of jasmine in your `protractor-config.js`:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    ...
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000 // 90s timeout
}
```

I hope this helps, otherwise please tell me so i can improve my answer ;-)

Comment: answer seems nice. i will try to implement, and i will let you know.

Comment: Great! No problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Protractor allows you to solve this problem using the 
`browser.forkNewDriverInstance(opt_useSameUrl, opt_copyMockModules)` method, which will return an independent browser object. Quoting the Protractor API overview from [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md) link, here is the official documentation for this-

> If you are testing apps where two browsers need to interact with each other (e.g. chat systems), you can do that with protractor by dynamically creating browsers on the go in your test. Protractor exposes a function in the browser object to help you achieve this: `browser.forkNewDriverInstance(opt_useSameUrl, opt_copyMockModules)`. Calling this will return a new independent browser object. The first parameter in the function denotes whether you want the new browser to start with the same url as the browser you forked from. The second parameter denotes whether you want the new browser to copy the mock modules from the browser you forked from.

```
browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
browser.addMockModule('moduleA', "angular.module('moduleA', []).value('version', '3');");

// To create a new browser.

var browser2 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();

// To create a new browser with url as 'http://www.angularjs.org':

var browser3 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true);

// To create a new browser with mock modules injected:
var browser4 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(false, true);

// To create a new browser with url as 'http://www.angularjs.org' and 
mock modules injected:
var browser4 = browser.forkNewDriverInstance(true, true);`
```

I suppose this is what you are looking for. As per the problem you have mentioned, you can specifically mention the browser object that you want to perform you action in- for eg- you can verify your message on the second instance using method like

```
 //get element text in second browser
  var element2=browser2.element;
  element2.getText().then(function(){
     //use an expect to verify the text
 });
```

Please go through the **[link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md)** given above for further explanation.

Comment: forkNewDriverInstance opens new browser instance. as i posted a picture,  another browser is already running, i want interaction in already running browser.

Comment: create a new browser window and then switch to that browser to perform next action

Comment: also your image says browser1 and browser2 which means two different instances of browser objects

Comment: new browser window is not a solution for my problem. because as i describe in picture, spec7 is dependent on the results of spec2 that is running in browser 1. so two browsers are there. when e2e test comes to spec7 file, it should do interaction between browser1 and browser2